# How to use mustache and jquery to display a single registry data from a large json?

Tags: jquery, json, html, mustache

This is a JSON I get from a "post" request inside the system I'm working on right now:

```
{
"return": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Bonnie",
        "last_name": "Little",
        "email": "blittle0@acquirethisname.com",
        "country": "Portugal",
        "ip_address": "48.218.146.63"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Judith",
        "last_name": "Martin",
        "email": "jmartin1@bing.com",
        "country": "Sierra Leone",
        "ip_address": "233.120.55.214"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "first_name": "Carl",
        "last_name": "Richardson",
        "email": "crichardson2@nsw.gov.au",
        "country": "Luxembourg",
        "ip_address": "26.228.244.43"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "first_name": "Carl",
        "last_name": "Richardson",
        "email": "crichardson2@nsw.gov.au",
        "country": "Luxembourg",
        "ip_address": "26.228.244.43"
    }
]
}
```

Do I have a way to use mustache to display only the data from the id=3 registry?

I'm using mustache and pure jquery

Comment: Yeah, you need to show your work i.e., code

Comment: Mustache is `logic-less`, so you need to put your `logic` (i.e. finding the item with id=3) outside your template. Use your tools for what they were meant for.

Comment: I am a designer trying to work as a programmer because of an emergency request, I'm pretty far from my habitual work, so, this is one of the issues. I have some knowledge about programming because of my almost done degree in IT but this was almost 10 years ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a mustache like template.  You'll need to find your item and then parse the template.  I don't the calls for the mustache library but it shouldn't be too different.

```js
var obj = {
  "return": [{
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Bonnie",
    "last_name": "Little",
    "email": "blittle0@acquirethisname.com",
    "country": "Portugal",
    "ip_address": "48.218.146.63"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Judith",
    "last_name": "Martin",
    "email": "jmartin1@bing.com",
    "country": "Sierra Leone",
    "ip_address": "233.120.55.214"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "first_name": "Carl",
    "last_name": "Richardson",
    "email": "crichardson2@nsw.gov.au",
    "country": "Luxembourg",
    "ip_address": "26.228.244.43"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "first_name": "Carl",
    "last_name": "Richardson",
    "email": "crichardson2@nsw.gov.au",
    "country": "Luxembourg",
    "ip_address": "26.228.244.43"
  }]
};

var arr = obj.return;
var i = 0;
var len = arr.length;
var found = null;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (arr[i].id == 3) {
    found = arr[i];
    break;
  }
}

if (found != null) {
  var el = document.getElementById("output");
  var template = el.innerHTML;
  template = template.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function(match, name) {
    return found[name];
  });
  el.innerHTML = template;
}
```

```html
<div id="output">
  <b>{{first_name}} {{last_name}}</b> is from <b>{{country}}</b>.
</div>
```